# Django mezzanine "do something" after a new post is added

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I'm using mezzanine for a project and there is a need to notify subscribers when a new post is added, I wanted to write my own view function so that when a new post is published, I can do something like:

```
# pseudo_code.py
blogposts.onAdd(notify())

def notify():
    email(users)
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is in the docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/

http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html#page-processors

Here is some code from a mezzanine project of mine:

models.py

```
from mezzanine.pages.models import Page
from django.db import models

class WorkOrderPage(Page): #create model that inherits from page
    header = models.CharField(max_length=3000,null=True)
```

admin.py

```
from .models import WorkOrderPage
from django.contrib import admin
from mezzanine.pages.admin import PageAdmin

admin.site.register(WorkOrderPage, PageAdmin) //make page available to admin
```

page_processors.py

```
from mezzanine.pages.page_processors import processor_for
from .models import WorkOrderPage
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

class NewWorkOrderForm(forms.Form):
    //create form

@processor_for(WorkOrderPage)
def newworkorder_form(request, page):
    form = NewWorkOrderForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewWorkOrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            from_email = 'xx@xx.com'
            to_email = 'yy@yy.com'
            subject, from_email, to = 'subject text', from_email, to_email
            text_content = 'content of email'
            html_content = 'html content'
            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject text, text_content, from_email, [to])
            msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
            msg.send()
            return redirect('/redirect to?')

    return {"form": form}
```

So you would create a 'work order page' in the admin,
That page would have a form, when they submit the form it sends an email.

Comment: thank you, this could work, but I'm not a fan of tweaking Mezzanine that much. I ended up having a admin-viewable button that says "send notification emails", which triggers the send-email event.

Comment: i know this old.. any links for your solution?

Comment: no, I ended up adding a button and bind whatever API endpoints that needs requested to that button. Solved my problem though.